# Visual Basic - Multicolumn listbox and adding items

Tags: vb.net, listbox, multiple-columns

So here's the thing; I'm making this home-made sign-up thing for a school project.

I've got first name, last name, date of birth, SS number among other things.

I can send data to another form's listbox
Dim SSID = (tx_SSP.Text)
        Datbase_of_User_Information.ListBox1.Items.Add(SSID)

However this will only add ONE item to the listbox.  I know there's a way to add in a multi-column data thing into the list
ex:
SSID | Fname | Lname | DoB

Something like the above.

But I've tried doing Listbox1.AddItem("row1 col1", SSID)
and it didn't work.

Comment: if your data comes from a database you can bind it to a DataGridView and let it create the columns and rows with one line of code

Comment: ListBox is a very simple control which cannot account for "proper" columns. The right approach here would be relying on another control, like `ListView` or `DataGridView`, which does have such a capability. If you want to rely on `ListBox` anyway (and set the columns "manually" by putting spaces in between), you can rely on `AddRange`. For example: `Dim source As Object() = New Object() {"1 2 3", "4 5 6", "7 8 9"}` and `yourListBox.Items.AddRange(source)`. Alternatively, you might use the `DataSource` property; example: `yourListBox.DataSource = source`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and I kind of cheated by just putting all the values together into one string and using tabs.

`Listbox1.Items.Add(SSID & "        " & Fname & "       " & Lname & "       " & DoB)`

I've heard a better solution would be to use a ListView if you want a true multi-column solution.